# Show that $\tan{x}<\frac{4x}{\pi}$, $0<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $$\tan{x}<\frac{4x}{\pi}, ~~0<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$$

I want to use appropriate Mean Value Theorem to solve it. Please help.

Comment: HINT: use that $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$$ and $$0<c<\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: As you are not at all a newcomer, why don't you show us what you have attempted, where you are blocked, etc ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Mean Value Theorem you get
$$
\tan x=\tan x-\tan0=(\tan)'(c)\,x=(1+\tan^2c)\,x\le2\,x,
$$
where $0<c<x<\pi/4$. But this is not what you want. Instead, use the fact that $\tan x$ is a convex function.